# Where to install GhostScript for imagick used by PHP on XAMPP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, xampp, ghostscript, imagick

I am trying to use imagick for image processing in PHP and GhostScript for converting PHP files to images. I moved all the needed .dll from the ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc11-x86 file downloaded into xampp/php/ext and add the extension = php_imagick.dll line in the php.ini file. The imagick extension is displayed when the phpinfo() is called and I can call the functions of the Imagick class.

However, my problem is that when I tried to convert a pdf file into an image, it gave me the following error message:

> ">"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   ">"'PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified. ' @
>   ">"error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/801' in
>   ">"C:\Users\Raymond\xampp\htdocs\phpTest\index.php:45 Stack trace: #0
>   ">"C:\Users\Raymond\xampp\htdocs\phpTest\index.php(45):
>   Imagick-">">__construct('C:\Users\Raymon...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   ">"C:\Users\Raymond\xampp\htdocs\phpTest\index.php on line 45

I figured the problem was caused because my imagick extension on xampp can not locate GhostScript. I downloaded GhostScript to my computer.

Comment: I just submitted an edit to your post. However, Can you clarify the "downloaded GhostScript" bit? Did you install it, put it somewhere, extract it, or just download it? You might also consider the `xampp` tag instead of `apache`.

Comment: William Kappler, thanks for the prompt reply. I downloaded the gs910w64.exe, ran it and installed it in the path C:\Users\Raymond\gs9.10 folder. My xampp is installed in the path C:\Users\Raymond\xampp

Comment: Did you install Ghostscript before Imagemagick and Imagick? If it is installed Imagemagick should find it when it is installed. Did you restart your PC after the install as I find that is sometimes required.

Comment: I installed Imagemagick and Imagick after GhostScript, Bonzo. I will reinstall them. Does it matter where the Imagemagick should be installed? I also restarted my PC. The problem was still there. Does it also matter where I install GhostScript?

Comment: I have never had a problem until I could not find the correct .dll for Imagick and gave up with it. I have always let Windows decide where to install Ghostscript and Imagemagick. Another thing is I always let Imagemagick add itself to the environmental path. Again I do not know if you need Imagemagick installed for Imagick to work but did it anyway as I use it with exec()

Comment: @RaymondWu did you find any effective solution of this? I'm also facing the same problem.

Comment: @RaymondWu I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution ?